# PhpStorm formats multiline array with double tab

Tags: php, arrays, format, phpstorm

The problem is that PhpStorm(10) formats array with double indentation instead of single. So I expect this

```
public function behaviors ()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => NestedSetsBehavior::className()
        ]
    ];
}
```

but get this

```
public function behaviors ()
{
    return [
            [
                    'class' => NestedSetsBehavior::className()
            ]
    ];
}
```

I've tried to change different settings for indentation including 'Continuation indent' but still get the same.

Comment: There is double indentation within array for the second example.

Comment: I've not found anything useful for my case in these two article. The first one is telling about manual indentation while I am talking about auto-formating. And there is no anything about arrays and indentation in the second one. But anyway thank you for trying to help. I have googled a lot and have not found solution for my problem so I post the question here.

Comment: Ok, wait for sometime. May be you got help. Good-luck

Comment: In case anyone interested in solution: I have not found the solution in settings but I have deleted whole settings folder and it helped.

Comment: @witzawitz is this formatting happening as you type or copy/pasting from somewhere? If copying from somewhere, can you post the code from before. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this, but haven't been able to find a fix yet.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I copy/pasted your example and did `Code -> Reformat Code`, the result is in the screen shot with single indentation. I highlighted the option which may be causing the issue you're experiencing.

I was using a Mac and PHPStorm 10 (like your's).

Comment: Changing this setting had no effect for me.

Comment: @LukeCarbis are you copy/pasting the code from somewhere and PhpStorm maintains indentation?